# Correct usage of the MVVM-Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I hope this question isn't to general.

I was used to implement my WPF-Applications within the MVVM-Pattern. So I alwayse created one Folder for the `View`, one for the `ViewModel` and one for the `Model` (and some other folders for Behaviours, Converter, ...)

First I've put the `MainWindowView.xaml` into the `View`-Folder. Then I've added the `MainWindowViewModel.cs` to the `ViewModel`-Folder. And after this I've added a `MainWindowModel.cs`-File to the `Model`-Folder.

And the `MainWindowModel.cs`-File is where I have the question.

I'm used to use this class for my business-logic like loading data from a database or parse an xml-file and put the results into a collection.

For example if I want to load data from a XML-File on a Button-Click I did it with something like:

**MainWindowView**

```
<Window x:Class="MVVMExample.View.MainWindowView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MVVMExample.ViewModel"
        Title="MainWindowView" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding LoadDataCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10" Content="Load data" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindowViewModel**

```
internal class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly MainWindowModel mainWindowModel;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        mainWindowModel = new MainWindowModel();
        mainWindowModel.XmlEntriesLoaded += XmlEntriesLoaded;
        LoadDataCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadData);
    }

    private void XmlEntriesLoaded(object sender, GenericEventArgs<List<XmlEntry>> e)
    {
        List<XmlEntry> entries = e.Value;
        // Display entries in ObservableCollection
    }

    private void LoadData(object parameter)
    {
        mainWindowModel.LoadData();
    }

    private ICommand loadDataCommand;
    public ICommand LoadDataCommand
    {
        get { return loadDataCommand; }
        set
        {
            loadDataCommand = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindowModel**

```
internal class MainWindowModel
{
    public EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<List<XmlEntry>>> XmlEntriesLoaded;

    public void LoadData()
    {
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
        {
            // Do load the data here and assign the result to e.Result
        };
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            EventHandler<GenericEventArgs<List<XmlEntry>>> temp = XmlEntriesLoaded;
            if (temp != null)
            {
                temp(this, new GenericEventArgs<List<XmlEntry>>((List<XmlEntry>) e.Result));
            }
        };
        backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

The class `XmlEntry` is also located in the `Model`-Folder.

Now I was told, that the Model-Layer only contains the Business-Objects and no logic like I did it in my `MainWindowModel`. And the interaction to load data or so should be located into the `ViewModel`. Is that rigth? So I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes model should not have function. You can do logic in view model or any other class and populate the model and then wrap the model properties with view model so automatically the properties will be updated (use onproperychanged event for each property)

Comment: Here is all you questions answered: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a fair few debates about this before. Your model is much more than a dumb data object, it should contain behaviors just like your **ViewModel**.

Consider the example:

```
class Camera
    {
        BitmapImage CurrentFrame { get; set; }
        BitmapImage CapturedFrame { get; set; }
        VideoCaptureDevice CaptureDevice { get; set; }

        void TakePhoto();
        void ClearFrame();
        void Reset();
    }
```

The above is just some example code with no implementation, but you get the idea.

The point here is that methods like `TakePhoto` and `Reset` make much more sense if they are contained within the **Model** as opposed to the **ViewModel**. One of the reasons why this is a good idea is because it ensures that your Models can be used by multiple ViewModels without having to implement the logic across multiple ViewModels, as the logic is contains within the Model.

That said, there are some scenarios where a Model does not have any behaviors and only serves as a data object.

To answer your question:

The **Model** only knows about itself, therefore in your scenario, it is the **ViewModel's** responsibility to load the Models. Putting your loading method in the ViewModel is correct.

Taking this a step further, it'd be an even better idea if your loading of models logic is contained within a **Service** class, where your ViewModel can reference the service in order to load the appropriate Models. This will allow  multiple ViewModels to reference the Service and reduce code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have said you're doing it *wrong* per se. Normally my Model classes would be pretty basic things which just defined the objects required by my program. The ViewModel contains a set of methods and properties which are bound by the View, and which make use of the Model classes. The 'normal' MVVM pattern would have 1 View to 1 ViewModel, and then a number of Model classes which define your business objects, and then whatever supplementary classes you needed to support the operations defined in the ViewModel.

I would generally put your 'LoadData' method into its own class called something like 'DataService', which would be responsible for whatever external data operations your program needs. It's different to your Model classes, which just define objects, but doesn't necessarily fall into the tightly defined scope of youir ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

The relation between `Model` - `ViewModel` - `View` is not 1:1:1.
It is rather M:N:O.
So multiple `Views` can use one `ViewModel` and also one `ViewModel` can use multiple `Models`.

Usually `Model` contains classes definig data structures and their relationships, like Entity framework classes. I usually have separate VS projects for `Model` classes. So e.g. if your app uses 3 databases you can have 3 models in your VS solution. The model classes names should follow your app's UML class model or your database model also with proper names. `MainWindowModel` is not a good name for model class - it suggests, that it belongs to `MainWindow`, which is wrong - it should contain generally usable classes.

So if the code for `LoadData()` in your `MainWindowModel` is generally useful and will be used by multiple `ViewModels` or other components, then you should place it into your `Model` in a class named e.g. `CustomerXMLData` . **But it is also possible to have a `ViewModel` that uses no `Model` classes at all**. I.e. you do not have to create `XXXWindowModel` class for every `ViewModel` - that is not the point of MVVM. The point is re-usability of modular code and good design without duplicate code.